# How to solve, Keyboard hide automatically when we work with multiple view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have two search textbox that will dynamically showing. One for portrait view and second for landscape view. We handled input text using flag in ViewDidLayoutSubviews() method. We have written a keyboard hide notification method as KeyboardWillHide(NSNotification notification)  for text value handling.

We are getting these issue. Please have a look
1. When we start typing ViewDidLayoutSubviews() method every time call on key press and reload textbox. So my keyboard unable to up. We have fixe this with checking a flag if keyboard will then return.
2. Now we are getting same issue that keyboard hide automatic when we press on mic for speak to write. KeyboardWillHide(NSNotification notification) method every time call and hide keyboard. Its also call when we touch on tableview.   
How to solve these issue ,Please help

```
 private void KeyboardWillHide(NSNotification notification)
    {

      string orientation = this.InterfaceOrientation.ToString();
            if ((orientation.ToString() == "Portrait" || orientation.ToString() == "PortraitUpsideDown") && KeyboardHideSameView == false )
            {
                SearchText= txtSearchKeywordLS.Text;
                txtSearchKeyword.Text = txtSearchKeywordLS.Text;

            }
            else if ((orientation.ToString() == "LandscapeRight" || orientation.ToString() == "LandscapeLeft") && KeyboardHideSameView == false )
            {
                SearchText = txtSearchKeyword.Text;
                txtSearchKeywordLS.Text = txtSearchKeyword.Text;

            }

            txtSearchKeyword.ResignFirstResponder();
            txtSearchKeywordLS.ResignFirstResponder();
            isKeyboardApear = false;
            KeyboardHideSameView = false;
        }

public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

        if (isKeyboardApear == true) return;
        applyViewGradient();

        var orientation = this.InterfaceOrientation;

        if (orientation.ToString() == "Portrait" || orientation.ToString() == "PortraitUpsideDown")
        {
            PortraitConst(this.View.Bounds.Height, this.View.Bounds.Width);

            this.vwLandscapeHead.Hidden = true;
            this.vwPortraitHead.Hidden = false;

            this.txtSearchKeyword.Text = SearchText;

            txtSearchKeyword.ResignFirstResponder();
            txtSearchKeywordLS.ResignFirstResponder();
        }
        else if (orientation.ToString() == "LandscapeRight" || orientation.ToString() == "LandscapeLeft")
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Landscape Mode");


           // this.addSubview(landscapeView, containerView);

            LandscapeConst(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width);

            applyViewGradient();

            this.vwPortraitHead.Hidden = true;
            this.vwLandscapeHead.Hidden = false;

            this.txtSearchKeywordLS.Text = SearchText;

            txtSearchKeyword.ResignFirstResponder();
            txtSearchKeywordLS.ResignFirstResponder();
        }
       // this.containerView.NeedsUpdateConstraints();

    }
```

Comment: Don't resign first responder all the time? Your pattern is super strange

Comment: But we have required resign first responder all the time because it will stuck to load design or dynamically contraints.

Comment: Hello,
We have solved it logically by using flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved it logically by using flags. 
We have declare a boolean flag `isKeyboardAppear=false` when view appear first. When keyboard appear we set this flag to true And we noticed ViewDidLayoutSubviews() method are calling on every key press, so we write this code

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews() 
{
 base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews(); 
 if (isKeyboardAppear == true) 
 { 
  return; 
 } 
}
```

When we hide keyboard manually we reset flag isKeyboardAppear=false .

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, it might be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Sure @JJJ 
We have declare a boolean flag `isKeyboardAppear=false` when view appear first. When keyboard appear we set this flag to true And we noticed `ViewDidLayoutSubviews()` method are calling on every key press, so we write this code
` public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

            if (isKeyboardAppear == true)
            {

                return;
            }
}`
When we hide keyboard manually we reset flag `isKeyboardAppear=false` .